# BigDecimal adding problems

Tags: java, bigdecimal

There's this code. The problem is the following: numar computes as it should, but fails to add to pi, which remains 0.0, unchanged. why?

```
 public static void piLeibniz(int numarZecimale)
{
    String piReal = "3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679";
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    BigDecimal numar ;
    BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal("0.0");

    for(int i = 0; i<=100000000;i++)
    {
        numar = new BigDecimal( 4*((Math.pow(-1, i))/((2*i)+1)));
        pi = pi.add(numar);
       //System.out.println(numar);
        String piString = pi.toString();
        System.out.println(piString);

        if(!piString.substring(0, numarZecimale).equals(piReal.substring(0, numarZecimale)))
        {
        } else {
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Pi este:" + piReal.substring(0, numarZecimale)+ " calculat in " + (t2-t1) + " ms");
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT (edited as Reimeus said):
If the method's parameter is higher than 3, it throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. why?

Comment: well for the second part your String is "4.0" so you cant get the 4th character...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`add` returns a new `BigDecimal` value which is immutable. The original value needs to be assigned to the result of the method otherwise the value of `pi` will remain at its original value

```
pi = pi.add(numar);
```

Comment: So easy to forget and also very easy to overlook in the docs.  I've been bit by this several times now in complex code despite both being a regular user of BigDecimal and a big fan of Immutability by default!

Answer (score 4):

You need to reassign the value of variable 'pi' to itself after adding:
pi = pi.add(numar);

public BigDecimal add(BigDecimal augend)

Returns a BigDecimal whose value is (this + augend), and whose scale is max(this.scale(), augend.scale()).